# Visual Basic error runtime error '91'

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Microsoft Visual Basic and I'm trying to run an Excel macro built to parse an internet explorer htlml file. However I keep getting the following error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. When I run microsoft visual basic I see the following highlighted in yellow:

```
Set nameElement = anElement.Children.Item(0).Children.Item(1).Children.Item(1).Children.Item(1).Children.Item(0).Children.Item(1)
```

Any suggestions on how to correct this error and get the macro up and running?

Comment: Yes. Stop doing foolish things like accessing `Children.Item(0).Children.Item(1)`. One of those `Children` is null, or one of the children's `Item` isn't assigned. Use intermediate variables to hold values instead of chaining things like that, and you can figure out which one of them isn't assigned when you think it should be.